# this.props.chatVisible is 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs

I want to use the chatVisible props in the class ChatTitleButton. But when I console.log(this.props.chatVisible); I will get undefined. And I don't know why I keep getting undefined. Because it have to function as a boolean so, React can render depending on that variable what html to render. I hope somebody can help me

```js
import ChatTitleButton from "./ChatTitleButton";

class Chat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      chatVisible: true,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div classname = "chat-widget" >
      <ChatTitleButton / >
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class ChatTitleButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.chatVisible === true) {
      return ( <
        div className = "chat-title-close" >
        <
        button onClick = {
          this.closeChat
        }
        className = "btn chat-close" > Chat beindigen < /button> <
        /div>

      )
    } else {
      return ( <
        div className = "chat-title-close" >
        <
        button onClick = {
          this.openChat
        }
        className = "btn chat-close" > Chat openen < /button> <
        /div>
      )
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use this.state.chatVisible ?

Comment: Note that you can cut that render method in half by using `Chat { this.props.chatVisible? "beindigen" : "openen"}` (also: if you get a basic, essential feature explained to you in five answers in under two minutes, you didn't do enough research. In this case you didn't read the docs, apparently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the prop to the component.
In your render statement instead of `<ChatTitleButton />` use `<ChatTitleButton chatVisible={this.state.chatVisible}/>`.

Answer (score 0):

`chatVisible` is not passed to `ChatTitleButton`, you need to pass it as a prop in order to access it in the child.

```
render() {
    return ( 
    <div classname = "chat-widget" >
      <ChatTitleButton chatVisible={this.state.chatVisible}/ >
    </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to transfer state of one component to another using prop [Ref](https://codeburst.io/react-js-pass-data-from-components-8965d7892ca2)

```
import ChatTitleButton from "./ChatTitleButton";

class Chat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      chatVisible: true,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div classname = "chat-widget" >
      <ChatTitleButton 
        chatVisible={this.state.chatVisible} // updated code
      / >
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: duplicate answer, to a question that should be flagged as RTFM

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to pass the props. You should put it as a parameter in the JSX tag

```
import ChatTitleButton from "./ChatTitleButton";

class Chat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      chatVisible: true,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div classname = "chat-widget" >
      <ChatTitleButton chatVisible={this.state.chatVisible} / >
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: duplicate answer, to a question that should be flagged as RTFM

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `chatVisible` into the component:

```
import ChatTitleButton from "./ChatTitleButton";

class Chat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      chatVisible: true
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { chatVisible } = this.state;
    return ( 
      <div classname="chat-widget">
        <ChatTitleButton chatVisible={chatVisible} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: duplicate answer, to a question that should be flagged as RTFM